# remove git repository binding from visual studio 2015

Tags: tfs

Initially my project was mapped to a git repository.I Want to remove git mapping and  bind it to tfs (vs2015).I removed .git folder and its related files from the solution(my local drive) and open the solution in vs2015 and change the source control option to tfs. when adding solution to the source control I'm getting the following error
"the current solution has projects that are located outside the solution folder.These projects will not be source controlled in git repository.To add all the projects to a single git repository please consider all projects under a single folder"
If I click on OK on this error dialog, it automatically adding git folder to the solution.

I removed source controler provider for GIT from the registry via regedit. Now when i try to add solution to the tfs I am getting the error "The project or solution you opened requires a source control plug-in that is unavailable at this time.

I've tried different ways nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new team project on the TFS web portal. 
Start Visual Studio session. Select Tools->Options->Plug-in Selection and switch current source control plug-in to "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server".
From Visual Studio connect to the TFS and select the collection and the newly created team project. A local folder will be created for your new team project.
Copy all your sources in the local folder of the new team project. 
Open the solution in the current session of Visual Studio. Add the solution node to the source control. Check in and your done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change or mix TFVC with Git in the same project. You need to create a TFVC project, then check in the sources to the new project.

If you don't need to keep the source history, just pull down and check into the new version control as Mircea mentioned above.

If you want to keep the history, just try to migrate all history of main branch from local repo to a new TFVC team project with following steps:

1. Create an empty TFVC team project
2. Go to your local Repo folder, and use `git-tf checkin --deep` command
   to checkin the local repo to a TFVC team project. By default, the
   checkin command will create a single TFS changeset for the aggregate
   of all changes made on the current branch in Git since the last
   checkin to TFS. When used with the **--deep** option, a TFS changeset
   will be created for each Git commit on the current branch since the
   last checkin to TFS.

[image]